# Adding socket.io before filter to dry certain tasks

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have some socket.io endpoints like so:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function (req) {
       socket.handshake.token.verify((err, decoded) => {
           console.log(decoded);
       });
    });

    socket.on('debug', function (req) {
       socket.handshake.token.verify((err, decoded) => {
           console.log(decoded);
       });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function (req) {
       socket.handshake.token.verify((err, decoded) => {
           console.log(decoded);
       });
    });
});
```

As you can see, each endpoint has duplicate tasks which is about decoding and verifying the token. Is there any way to do it with a middleware or a before filter, such as:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.before((req, res) =>  {
       socket.handshake.token.verify((err, decoded) => {
           console.log(decoded);
       });
    }); 

    // Routes are defined here
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own function/method like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.onVerify = function(msg, fn) {
        socket.on(msg, function(data) {
            socket.handshake.token.verify((err, decoded) => {
               console.log(decoded);
            });
            fn(data);
        });

    }

    socket.onVerify('chat message', function (req) {
        // code here
    });

    socket.onVerify('debug', function (req) {
        // code here
    });

    socket.onVerify('disconnect', function (req) {
        // code here
    });
});
```

Comment: You're amazing. I should hit my head to walls for not thinking about this before. Is there any reason you name it as fn? I usually see fn in JS projects while on other languages it is mostly cb. Ps. Can't upvote since it requires 15 points.

Comment: @Doge - `fn` versus `cb` is just personal style.